# ElectronJS: logging method fires multiple times when don't wanted when using invoke/handle

Tags: javascript, electron, invoke, handle

As the title states. I have this problem with my ElectronJS project. When I try to log an output from an invoked handler, the logging happens multiple times, even though the function is run only once. What could be the cause of this?

The function is run only once, for each class object created. See GIF at the bottom to see the problem "in action".

I have tried removing the handler and listeners, but that just makes it so that the next object won't be able invoke `downloadPoster`..

Thanks in advance for any help.

Here is how the objects are instanciated and "processed".

```
// On drop
window.ondrop = async function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    body.classList.remove('file-hover');
    for (var [i, file] of Object.entries(e.dataTransfer.files)) {
        var x = new Movie(file.path);
        await x.process();
    }
    return false;
};
```

Here is the function from the class in `renderer.js`

```
/**
* Download poster file for movie
*/
async downloadPoster() {

    // This is the url used to search for the poster we want
    var searchUrl = new URL(Config.api.searchUrl);
    searchUrl.search = new URLSearchParams({
        page: 1, 
        api_key: Config.api.key,
        query: this.#movie.tags.title,
        year: this.#movie.tags.year
    });

    // Search for poster in the main thread
    await axios.get(searchUrl.href)
    .then(async (resp) => {

        // No results
        if (resp.data.total_results <= 0) {
            this.log('No poster found', 'error');
            return;
        } 
            
        // Invoke poster download
        const result = await ipcRenderer.invoke('downloadPoster', {
            src: Config.api.posterUrl + resp.data.results[0].poster_path,
            dest: path.join(this.#movie.new.absolutePath, Config.api.posterFilename)
        })
        
        // This shows "undefined"    
        this.log(result);

    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
            this.log('Could not search for poster: ' + err, 'error');
    });

}
```

Here is the handler function from the `main.js`

```
// Download poster
ipcMain.handle('downloadPoster', async (event, args) => {

    await axios.get(args.src, { responseType: 'stream' })
    .then(async (resp) => {

        const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(args.dest);

        // Write data to file
        await resp.data.pipe(writeStream);
        
        // When finished, send reply back
        writeStream.on('finish', async () => {
            return {
                success: true,
                message: 'Poster downloaded'
            }
        });

        // On error writing, send reply back
        writeStream.on('error', async (err) => {
            return {
                success: false,
                message: 'Could not write poster to file: ' + err
            }
        });

    })
    .catch(async (err) => {
        return {
            success: false,
            message: 'Could not download poster: ' + err
        }
    });

});
```

[image: No actual pirated material. Just test folders.]

Comment: Why are you `await`ing with a `.then()` and a `.catch()`? I would remove the `async/await` from  downloadPoster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misunderstanding `invoke`/`handle`. The whole point of using that feature is that the return value from the handler in the main process is returned by the invoke method in the renderer. So you can do this:

```js
// main.js
ipcMain.handle('some-command', async (evt, data) => {
// do something with data, the handler can also be async
 const value = await getSomeValue();
 return doSomething(data, value);
}
```

```js
// renderer.js
(async () => {
 const invokeReturn = await ipcRenderer.invoke('some-command', data);
 // invokeReturn will contain the result of doSomething(data, value) from main
})
```

I would need to do some debugging on your code to be sure but my instinct is that the behavior is caused by this bit of code:

```js
// Poster download reply from the invoke above
ipcRenderer.on('downloadPosterReply', async (event, args) => {
```

You're setting a listener and never removing it, so with each function call there's a new handler added, causing more and more logs to appear. Thanks to `invoke`/`handle`, you don't need to use an `on` handler here at all.

Comment: I have deffo misunderstood how invoke/handle are to used as you described. Thanks for checking it out.

Comment: Okay, so I haved edited it a bit. And it seems to be working, almost. Following how you described it I now invoke the command and in my handler I return something. But I cannot seem to access the response from the handler as it always ends up being "undefined". I have updated the code in my post so you can see it. Do you know why it just shows as undefined?

Comment: You need to return the promise chain. Right now the handler in main executes `axios.get` but doesn't return anything. You need to do `return axios.get(...).then(...)`. You can also skip the `async`, since you're just using regular promise chaining and not `await`.

Comment: Oh man, thanks! Finally got it working by returning a new promise and resolving the message back to the renderer. Works perfectly. Thanks again!